# Can I override the dijit/form/_AutoCompleterMixin to match any part of string not only beginning string?

Tags: autocomplete, dojo, dijit.form, ibm-bpm

I have a customized single select on ibm bpm using the dojo toolkit.
It is implemented from dijit.form.FilteringSelect which extends dijit.form.ComboboxMixin which extends dijit/form/_AutoCompleterMixin where if user types in a partial string, highlight the entries in the drop down list that start with that partial string

I need if user types in a partial string, highlight the entries in the drop down list that CONTAIN with that partial string.

So Is it possible I override this dojo component?
and what are the risks?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable substring search when using FilteringSelect component as follows:

```
var obj = new FilteringSelect({
  queryExpr:"*${0}*", //enables substring search
  autoComplete:false, //prevents autocomplete
  //other arguments
});
```

Here is a working sample: https://codepen.io/carlosnantes/pen/JjPXYeJ